# SQLite Xamarin - Select the highest date of each individual ID (Using Linq expressions)

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq, listview, xamarin

Hi I'm creating a message app on Xamarin. And I'm using SQLite (Async) to store the data locally on the phone.

I have three tables:

1. Contacts:

   - Username (PK)
   - Image
2. Conversations

   - ConversationID (PK)
   - LastMessage
   - Username (FK)
3. Messages

   - ID (PK)
   - Text
   - Date
   - Username (FK)
   - ConversationID (FK)

I have a collection of Conversations that are displayed in a ListView using an ObservableCollection. Basically I want to sort them, so that the conversation with the newest message (highest date) appears first.

I've tried making a few Linq expressions to solve that. Unfortunately with no luck. 
I tried to retrieve a list of only the newest Message object for each ConversationID, and then sort the ObservableCollection by the dates. But I'm not sure how to make that in practice.

```
        public Task<Message> GetNewestMessage()
    {

        return _database.Table<Message>().OrderByDescending(m => m.Date).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
```

This method only returns a single item, which is the newest message of all conversations. But I want one for each conversation.

I've also tried this expression in the ViewModel where the ListViews binding context is set:

```
Conversations.OrderBy(c => c.Messages.Max(m => m.Date));
```

Problem is that the Messages property in Conversation is a [OneToMany] but seems to be empty I think. (I'm using Sqlite.Net.Extensions to create relations)

[image: Ideal]

Comment: Have a look at `GroupBy` method.

Comment: Why dont you break it in 2 steps. From database group the messages by conversationId. That's your list 1.list1 count is no of conversations. And then run orderbydescendcing on each group to get latest msg.